# How to write the first test for an "add" functionality

Tags: c++, unit-testing, tdd

I had problems finding a good question title, so feel free to improve on that.

I want to implement an [Entity Component System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system) in C++, and wish to use TDD for the first time. Now I have doubts about how useful TDD is when the target "architecture" is already specified, but want to try it anyway. My problem is more of a TDD problem though, and I could have run into it in another context as well:

The first test was supposed to check that I can add a `Component` to an `Entity` as an `Entity` should "possess" a set of `Component`s (maybe this is a bad test and the problem lies here already?). So far no code exists and I'm facing a dilemma which might not be one. I could write a test that does this:

```
Entity e;
Component c;
e.add(c);
```

But how would I assert that the `add` has worked correctly? I know I am going to need some sort of `has_component` method sooner or later, but I shouldn't implement additional functionality now, or should I?
I could also make `Entity` have some list type in its public interface and use that in the test, and refactor that "away" later.

What is a correct approach here? It might be my mindset for TDD is totally off, so I'm grateful for any input!

Comment: I'm also unsure about the tags. Does this question merit the C++ tag, or is it irrelevant here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first test is a good start.  Maybe think about error checking: is there a return code from add, to tell that it did work or not ? Or is it supposed to throw an exception if something goes wrong ?

**Preferred approach**

Knowing that you'll need a method `has_component()` for the `Entity` class,  just add it to the class definition, with a stub implementation that always return `false` (and a big comment `// TO DO !!`).

Your next test would then be:

```
assert(! e.has_component(c) ); 
e.add(c);
assert(e.has_component(c)); // or return FAIL to your test framework.
```

The [principle](http://agiledata.org/essays/tdd.html) is that your test will fail until both functions are correct.

**What are the alternatives**

- use a simpler member, such as `number_of_components()` to check that you're on the right track (i.e. number increases when adding a new component; number remains same when adding same component twice).
- let the test code inspect the internals of your `Entity`.  I don't like this approach, because it breaks the rules of encapsulation.
- make a a [test double](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html) that provides emulated/simulated answer for `has_component()`. Would it be a very complex feature, this would be the way to go.  But for simple features like here, this might be overkill.
- if you'd have a dispatching function that forwards calls from `Entity` to `Components` you could use it to check if c reacts.

Comment: In addition to this, writing degenerate test cases can sometimes help, for example, write a test for what would happen if the user passes `null` to the `add` method.

Comment: Thank you for this great input! I understand the merits of the different ways to go about it now I think. I try to adhere to "one assert per test" though. Your post also made me think of different ways to tackle the `Entity` class and what would happen if I e.g. wrote a test for different methods first.